# Exact sequences and characteristic ideal of modules over a principal ideal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a principal ideal ring, which is not a field, and $M$ be a torsion module, then there is an isomorphism due to the theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal domain

$ M \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^s R/(c_i) $

where $c_i \in R\setminus (R^* \cup \{0\})$ and $c_1\mid\ldots\mid c_s$. We call $\chi(M):= (c_1\cdot\ldots\cdot c_s)\subset R$ the *characteristic ideal* of $M$.
Now let $M'$ and $M''$ be torsion modules as well and $0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$ be an exact sequence of $R$-modules, then it holds that $\chi(M)=\chi(M')\cdot\chi(M'')$. Why?

I know that for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ this is in fact nothing but Lagrange's theorem, but why is it the case for any principal ideal domain?

Comment: I want to point out that the first thing that should be checked is that the definition of $\chi(M)$ is well-defined: if you write $M$ as a direct sum of cyclic torsion $R$-modules in two ways, why do the calculations of $\chi(M)$ with each direct sum agree?  See Theorem 5.5 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/modulesoverPID.pdf.  Since $\chi(M)$ generalizes the concept of cardinality of finite abelian groups (when $R = \mathbf Z$), I write $\chi(M)$ there as ${\rm card}_R(M)$.

Comment: The definition is well-defined since the $c_i$ are the "elementary divisors" of this module (I don't know the exact English term) and they are unique up to being associated, thus $\chi(M)$ is well-defined.

Comment: I had not noticed the part where you wrote the divisibility conditions $c_1 \mid \cdots \mid c_s$.  I would say it is still useful that you can compute $\chi(M)$ using an *arbitrary*  decomposition of $M$ into a direct sum of cyclic modules, not just the one using elementary divisors. That's analogous to saying you can compute the order of a finite abelian group from an arbitrary direct sum decomposition of it into cyclic groups, and it's clear that this is more useful than only being able to compute the order from a direct sum decomposition with elementary divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $M$ is generated by $x_1, \cdots, x_n$, define $\eta: R^n \to M, \sum_i a_i e_i \mapsto \sum_i a_i x_i$, where $e_1, \cdots, e_n$ is basis of $R^n$.

$N=$ker($\eta$) and $N''=$ker($\beta \circ \eta$) are free $R$-module of rank $n$.($\beta$ is the map $M \to M''$.) Then $N \subset N''$.

a set of generator of $N''$: $(f_1, \cdots, f_n)=(e_1, \cdots, e_n)A$. $A$ is a matrix with entry in $R$.

a set of generator of $N$: $(g_1, \cdots, g_n)=(f_1, \cdots, f_n)B=(e_1, \cdots, e_n)AB$.

isomorphism theorem says a matrix is equivalent to a diagonal matrix diag($d_1, \cdots, d_n)$ with $d_i | d_{i+1}$.

Since determinant of an invertible matrix is an invertible element in $R$. We have $\chi(M'')=(\text{det} A)$, $\chi(M)=(\text{det} AB)$, notice $M' \simeq N''/N$, $N$ is a submodule of rank $n$ of a free $R$-module $N''$, so $\chi(M')=(\text{det} B)$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your proof. Could you elaborate?